# Every finitely generated module is sum of local modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

**Note:** All modules are over a $K$-algebra $A$ with $K$ a field and the underlying ring of $A$ is unital (but not necessarily commutative).

**Definition:** A module $V$ is *local* if there is a maximal submodule $U$ of $V$ such that all proper submodules of $V$ are contained in $U$.

> Show that every module $V$ of finite length is the sum of all local submodules.

---

I'm completely stumped. What I know is that

1. a module of finite length is finitely generated,
2. in a finitely generated module, every proper submodule is contained in some maximal submodule,
3. a lot of facts about socles and radicals (this might help).

Maybe one could try to show that if $L$ is the sum of all local submodules, then $V = \mathrm{rad}(V) + L$.
Since the radical is small in the finitely generated $V$, we have $L = V$.

Comment: Do you know what a [composition series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series) is?

Comment: Do you have any conditions on the ring?

Comment: @Pedro Of course, otherwise how do you define the length of a module?

Comment: @JonasLinssen Actually, my course on representation theory deals with $K$-algebras with $K$ a field, so you might assume that all modules have underlying vector spaces. I will edit the problem accordingly.